# Any way for django user profile editable only by admin interface?

Tags: django, admin, profile

Is there any way to give the user profile field a permission to make it only be editable by the admin interface? The user should only be able to see the value in their profile page but can't change it.

Comment: How is the user exposed to their profile? Through the django admin or through a custom interface? You can easily apply permission using django's built in groups https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, no. There's no flag or such that will only allow an object to be managed through the Django admin. *But*, you have to provide some other way to manage the object, so if you don't want something to be editable other than via the admin interface, simply don't provide another way to edit it. Not sure what the issue is here.